# Login via HttpClient in Web API Exception await client.PostAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, httpclient

I have created an ASP.net project WebAPI and an MVC Project.
When i try to login via HttpClient with the mvc project to the web api it throws an exception.

MVC code,

Login in AccountController:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        try
        {
            var client = WebApiHttpClient.GetClient();
            string username = model.Email;
            string password = model.Password;
            HttpContent content = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/Token", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //string contentResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //return Content(contentResponse);
                TokenResponse tokenResponse =
                await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenResponse>();
                WebApiHttpClient.storeToken(tokenResponse);
                // return Content(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Error in: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return Content("Error catch .");
        }
    }
```

WebapiHtppClient class: used to connect to the API

```
  public class WebApiHttpClient
{
    public const string WebApiBaseAddress = "https://localhost:44379/";
    public static HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebApiBaseAddress);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        if (session["token"] != null)
        {
            TokenResponse tokenResponse = getToken();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", tokenResponse.AccessToken);
        }

        return client;
    }

    public static void storeToken(TokenResponse token)
    {
        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        session["token"] = token;
    }
    public static TokenResponse getToken()
    {
        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        return (TokenResponse)session["token"];
    }

}

public class TokenResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("userName")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(".issued")]
    public string IssuedAt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(".expires")]
    public string ExpiresAt { get; set; }
}
```

i already tried a lot of anwsers from here but didnt find results.
One was in the await client.PostAsync("/Token", content) , just put the "Token"

With the Postman from chrome i can do the login and see the stuff in the Web Api
with this

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlynr.png)

Error catch:An error occurred while sending the request. mscorlib at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at WebApplication1.Controllers.AccountController.d__11.MoveNext() in C:\wamp\www\arqsi\it1\iteracao3\iteracao3\WebApplication1\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 88

Comment: What is the exception? Is you content type matching with API?

Comment: the exception is the Content("Error catch .");

Comment: Catch the exception message. Catch(Exception ex) { return Content("Error catch"+ex.Message + ex.Source + ex.StackTrace);}

Comment: Error catch:An error occurred while sending the request. mscorlib at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at WebApplication1.Controllers.AccountController.d__11.MoveNext() in C:\wamp\www\arqsi\it1\iteracao3\iteracao3\WebApplication1\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 88

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you put a debugger
(in AccountController at=> if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode))
At this point check
 1)if you are able to hit the API,
 2)if token is returned in your response variable